# Logout user when app redirect to another app Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, external, redirect, flow-router

I have 2 apps, one for auth while the other for products. After login or verification of email, the user is redirected to the products app. On redirection, the recently logged in user is instantly logged out, so a reference to the logged in user becomes `null`, and I'll need the logged in credentials in the auth app to authenticate on the second. How do I maintain the logged in state in the auth app when it has redirected to the products app?

This is the login function on the auth app

```
var callLogin = function (email, password, router) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, ( error )=> {
        if (error) {
            sAlert.error( error );
        } else {
            sAlert.success("Logged in successfully");
             window.location.replace( "http://localhost:3300/" + Meteor.userId() );
        } 
    });
}
```

This is the onCreated function on the products app

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {

        let router = FlowRouter.getParam("_id");
        let AuthConnection = DDP.connect( AuthURL );

         if ( AuthConnection ) {
            console.log( router );
            AuthConnection.call('logins.user', router, ( error, response )=> {
                if ( error ) {
                    console.log( error );
                } console.log( response );
            } );
        }
      });
```

The logged in user is always present until the redirection that it becomes null. What do I do to maintain the logged in state of the user in the auth app?

Answer (score 0):

I assume both apps connect to the same database?

When you redirect your local state changes - specifically in this case your local storage state which tracks user resume tokens.

If you want to allow one app to authenticate for another you need some form of SSO - a trivial implementation would be after login to request a resumeToken from the server, pass that to your second app in the URL, then use `Meteor.loginWithToken`. A more hacky (but maybe simpler?) way might be to copy the token saved in localStorage from app1, pass it in the URL to app2 then use save it there too.

Comment: Thank you very much @Zack, No, the apps are of diff databases. Nevertheless, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @kehinde if the apps connect to different databases this wont work, can you explain your use case a little more?

Comment: @Zach Newsham, what I want to do is to have full separation of all the apps but they should only share data via subscription, methods, and publication. My reason is to make sure the other app should not be able to write directly to the collection on another app. Though I have created the monolithic app and the performance would be degrading overtime. To quickly address this, i have to break it down to diff scalable modules. If you don't mind, I can share a diagram of the model privately with you.

Comment: @kehinde, sure - share the diagram. But if they don't share a database, then logging in through a different app is a bit more difficult - you could probably setup your "login app" as a SSO provider (like facebook or google)